# Page reload via ajax

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

Is it a proper approach to reload the page? Or how to do better?

Thanks in advance)

**My view**:

```
def logout(request):
  auth.logout(request)
  html = render(request, 'base.html')
  return html
```

**Ajax**:

```
$('a[href$="logout/"]').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "logout" %}',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $('body').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false
});
```

Comment: It depends what you need to achieve. When you logout from somewhere usually it's more logical to reload the page. On the other hand if you have single page app it may be better to make ajax request and refresh the state without reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading all of you pages like this?
If it is traditional multi page web application, why not just send regular Http request instead of XMLHttp request?

If you load all pages like this `$('body').html(data);` then you will have some performance issues after some time.
If you don't want to reload your pages, create a Single Page Application (SPA) with React, Angular or Vue.

Comment: I wanted to refresh my page via ajax, but I don`t know how ro return proper HttpResponse, so I decided to that it would be ok to refresh page in such way. Could you please make some examples how to make it better?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood you.
If you want to reload page on response you can do it via [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).
`window.location.reload();`